# Open source projects to learn CanCan gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Is there any good open source project which has Can Can implemented completely.

Comment: If you find it hard to learn CanCan by reading its wiki, you'll have a lot of struggle in your professional life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails 3.2+ use the rails composer tool:

http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/

Answer (score 1):

Try the [rails app composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) script. It's great. You can set up a fully functioning app with devise, rolify, cancan, rspec and much much more. Just run the script, answer the questions and it will generate the app for you. Then you can poke around and see how it's implemented.

You can also watch this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) on cancan and download the example source code.